# Android, Database count for each record

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, count

I have a ListView in my Class which will display a list of every category in the database table.  In that list view I have three TextViews, ROWID CategoryName and CategoryCount respectively as so:

```
        private void populateCategoryList() {
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        TextView tvCategoryItem = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCategoryItem);
        TextView tvCatID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCatID);
        TextView tvCatCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCatCount);

        Cursor cursor = db.getCategories();

        // Allow activity to manage lifetime of the cursor.
        // DEPRECATED! Runs on the UI thread, OK for small/short queries.
//      startManagingCursor(cursor);        //TODO Turned off because on back from contact details made a closed cursor error

        // Setup mapping from cursor to view fields:
        String[] fromFieldNames = new String[] { db.KEY_ROWID, db.KEY_CATEGORY };
        int[] toViewIDs = new int[] { R.id.tvCatID, R.id.tvCategoryItem };

        SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, // Context
                R.layout.item_categorylist, // Row layout template
                cursor, // cursor (set of DB records to map)
                fromFieldNames, // DB Column names
                toViewIDs // View IDs to put information in
        );

        /****** COUNT CODE ******/
        // tvCatCount = (db.countCategory(category));

        // Set the adapter for the list view
        lvCategories = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvCategories);
        lvCategories.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
        db.close();
```

You can see in the toFields above that I do not yet have a field set for the count.  I will use tvCatCount for this.  The question is, how and where do I insert the count code.  In this case the count?  I think that the countCategory will need to be a for loop where it should get the id of the current category entry for that row, call the db.countCategory and tehn set the value in the TextView to the returned result?

Here is the db.countCategory code:

```
public int countCategory(category){

SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
String[] categoryColumns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_CATEGORY };

Cursor c = db.query(CATEGORY_TABLE, null, null, null, KEY_CATEGORY + "=" + category, null, null);
int result = c.getCount();
c.close();
Log.i("DATABASE", "Category Count for id " + id + "is " + result);
return result;
}
```

which should count every entry in the table equal to the value of "id".  This code already works elsewhere, so I am not too worried about it, but to count for each row in a listview, that is a different animal.

Comment: The `rowid` typically is the primary key, which implies that every count is 1. Is it? Show your database schema.

Comment: ahh yeah actually you are right, but still if I use the category name instead, it would be the same question.

Comment: Lemme clarify a bit.  I have an expense table which will use the categories.  I want to count each instance of that category in the expense table and diplay the count for each category in teh Categories List View.  SO I can count the ID or the name, however it is stored..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the count of expenses for each category, you would need a table with these columns:

```
_id | CategoryName | Count
```

To compute this, you have to join the categories table to the expenses table, and use GROUP BY to get one output row for each distinct category value:

```
SELECT Category.rowid AS _id,
       Category.Name,
       COUNT(*) AS NumberOfExpenses
FROM Category
JOIN Expenses ON Category.rowid = Expenses.CategoryID
GROUP BY Category.rowid
```

Comment: thank you very much.  I have no idea why I did not think of that.